# EXTRACT command returns Null in MYSQL .. any advice please?

Tags: sql, extract

I'm trying to pull year from order_Date from the table called warehouse.big_w_orders. order_date contains a date format such as 1/1/2019 but the data type is text. When I write the query below it just returns 'null' not 2019. I tried to use CAST fuction to change the data type to date or even float but it didn't work either.

SELECT extract(year from order_date) FROM warehouse.big_w_orders;

Could someone please help me out here? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the data type of `order_date` is text. So technically, you cannot extract year from text. You need to convert your text to a date first.

Try this:

```sql
SELECT extract(year from to_date(order_date,'DD/MM/YYYY')) FROM warehouse.big_w_orders;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried your suggestion but it didn't work either. Could you please share how to cast text type to date type? CAST doesn't seem to work :( Thanks!!